# c++ : double iteration through map

Tags: c++, dictionary, iterator

I would like to iterate through a map but the inner loop would just iterate through the upper part of the elements.
With a vector it would look like that :

```
for(auto element1 = myVector.begin() ; element1 != myVector.end() ; ++element1){
    for(auto element2 = element1 + 1; element2 != myVector.end() ; ++element2){
         //my stuff
    }
}
```

But with a map `element1 + 1` returns an error `no operator matches this operand`.. I believe it comes from the fact that the element are not ordered in a map.

So how could I do that properly ? I am currently using this messy workaround that requires a test in each loop :

```
for(auto element1 = myMap.begin() ; element1 != myMap.end() ; ++element1){
    for(auto element2 = element1; element2 != myMap.end() ; ++element2){
         if(element->first != element2->first)
         //my stuff
    }
}
```

Comment: @Pixelchemist: Right, I can't read

Comment: elements in a `map` are ordered by the key.  The reason `element1 + 1` can't be used is because the iterators associated with a map are not random access iterators. You can increment them, but you can't add 1 to them.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use `std::next` to do this:

```
for(auto element1 = myMap.begin() ; element1 != myMap.end() ; ++element1) {
    for(auto element2 = std::next(element1) ; element2 != myMap.end() ; ++element2) {
        //my stuff
    }
}
```

Here is some additional background information about `std::next`. `std::next` has an optional second argument which is the number of elements to follow the passed iterator. For example `std::next(element1, 2)` would return an iterator for the 2nd element after `element1`. As has been pointed out in the comments, you **must** be careful when using `std::next`, especially in loops.  If `it` points to the element before `myMap.end()`, then using `std::next(it, 2)` results in undefined behavior. You want to make sure that using this will never pass the end of the container.

You can think of `std::next` as if it were implemented like this:

```
// If distance is negative, then i must meet the requirements of BidirectionalIterator
// Otherwise, i must meet the requirements of ForwardIterator.
template<class ForwardIterator>
ForwardIterator next(ForwardInterator i, int distance) {
    for( ; distance < 0 ; ++distance) {
        --i;
    }
    for( ; distance > 0 ; --distance) {
        ++i;
    }

    return i;
}
```

Which can be equivalently implemented like this:

```
template<class ForwardIterator>
ForwardIterator next(ForwardIterator i, int distance) {
    std::advance(i, distance);
    return i;
}
```

Comment: `std::next(element1, 2)` cannot be used here

Comment: @Slava Why?  `next()` takes a forward iterator and a map has a bidirectional iterator.

Comment: @Daniel because element2 will go out of bounds at the end of the first loop

Comment: @Daniel: the compiler will let you use it, but you can't use it in this particular situation because when `element1` happens to refer to the last element in the map you'll get undefined behavior.

Comment: @MichaelBurr `element1` will never equal end as the loop is `element1 != myMap.end() `

Comment: @Slava Ohhhh that's what you mean. I thought you meant it was inapplicable here. I was just trying to tell the OP about the optional second argument, not directly related to the question. I'll clarify.

Comment: @NathanOliver `myMap.end()` is the iterator _after_ the end of the map.

Comment: never mind.  Just realized I am arguing against a point that no longer exist since the comment was edited.

Comment: I have one more question : does `std::next(element1)` modify the variable element1 or not ?

Comment: @Arcyno as you can see from the implementations, `element1` is not modified.

Answer (score 1):

Even if you didn't know about some of the newer C++ facilities like `std::next()` (which is a good way to solve this problem), this seems to be a rather basic problem to solve:

```
for(auto element1 = myMap.begin() ; element1 != myMap.end() ; ++element1){
    auto element2 = element1;
    ++element2;
    for(; element2 != myMap.end() ; ++element2){
         //my stuff
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simplest solution would be to skip first one:

```
for(auto element1 = myMap.begin() ; element1 != myMap.end() ; ++element1){
    for(auto element2 = element1; element2 != myMap.end() ; ++element2){
         if( element2 == element1 ) continue;
         //my stuff
    }
}
```

Comment: The 2nd snippet moves `element1` too, which is not intended.

Comment: @timrau it moves element1 there instead of doing that in first `for`

Comment: But the 1st element is just skipped by both iterators

Comment: @timrau ah you mean first iterator most probably would be used as well, you are right. Removed, thanks. I did not like that code, I felt it was not right. :)